# iOS Swift Dictionary Cloning

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary that I make copies of.  After I make the copies I want to change the values in each dictionary independently.  However, when I change one all the others change.  It's almost like the copies are just pointers back to the original.  My code to set them is:

```
var nf = text?.toInt()!
var creatureInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
for var c = 0;c<nf;c++ {
    creatureInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
    creatureInfo = getCreature(name)
    creatureInfo.setValue("creature", forKey: "combat-type")
    combatants.append(creatureInfo)
}
```

I thought at doing creatureInfo = NSMutableDictionary() in the loop would work but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @zneak's answer is the way to go.  If you *must* stick with `NSMutableDictionary`, then this should work:

```
var creatureInfo = getCreature(name).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
creatureInfo["combat-type"] = "creature"
combatants.append(creatureInfo)
```

Comment: Your solution worked best for me since it required the least amount of code rewriting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableDictionary` is a reference type (it's a `class`, not a `struct`) from the Cocoa legacy. If it looks like the copies are just pointers back to the original, that's because they are: `getCreature` most likely always returns the same instance.

Use the Swift [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113) type to get dictionaries that are treated as value types. You can declare one with the syntax `[KeyType: ValueType]`.

```
var creatureInfo: [String: String] = getCreature(name) as! [String: String]
creatureInfo["combat-type"] = "creature"
combatants.append(creatureInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  That makes more sense to me than the NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary approach for what I  need.